error: could not compile `spl-type-length-value`
Running cargo build with the following dependencies:
[dependencies]
solana-sdk = "1.18.17"
solana-client = "1.18.17"

Results in the following compile errors:
error[E0659]: `solana_program` is ambiguous
 --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/error.rs:6:1
  |
6 | #[spl_program_error(hash_error_code_start = 1_202_666_432)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous name
  |
  = note: ambiguous because of a conflict between a name from a glob import and an outer scope during import or macro resolution
  = note: `solana_program` could refer to a crate passed with `--extern`
  = help: use `::solana_program` to refer to this crate unambiguously
note: `solana_program` could also refer to the crate imported here
 --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/error.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use spl_program_error::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: consider adding an explicit import of `solana_program` to disambiguate
  = help: or use `self::solana_program` to refer to this crate unambiguously
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `spl_program_error` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
  --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:49:10
   |
39 |   ) -> Result<TlvIndices, ProgramError> {
   |        -------------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
47 |           let discriminator = ArrayDiscriminator::try_from(
   |  _____________________________-
48 | |             &tlv_data[tlv_indices.type_start..tlv_indices.length_start],
49 | |         )?;
   | |         -^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<TlvIndices, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
   | |_________|
   |           this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `Result<TlvIndices, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<TlvError>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:63:51
   |
63 |                 return Err(TlvError::TypeNotFound.into());
   |                                                   ^^^^ the trait `From<TlvError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `TlvError: Into<_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `TlvError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
  --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:67:99
   |
39 | ) -> Result<TlvIndices, ProgramError> {
   |      -------------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
67 |             pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&tlv_data[tlv_indices.length_start..tlv_indices.value_start])?;
   |             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<TlvIndices, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
   |             |
   |             this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `Result<TlvIndices, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
  --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:98:10
   |
80 |   ) -> Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), ProgramError> {
   |        ------------------------------------------------------ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
96 |           let discriminator = ArrayDiscriminator::try_from(
   |  _____________________________-
97 | |             &tlv_data[tlv_indices.type_start..tlv_indices.length_start],
98 | |         )?;
   | |         -^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
   | |_________|
   |           this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
   = note: required for `Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:109:14
    |
80  |   ) -> Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), ProgramError> {
    |        ------------------------------------------------------ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
107 |               let length = pod_from_bytes::<Length>(
    |  __________________________-
108 | |                 &tlv_data[tlv_indices.length_start..tlv_indices.value_start],
109 | |             )?;
    | |             -^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    | |_____________|
    |               this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:141:80
    |
127 | ) -> Result<&[u8], ProgramError> {
    |      --------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
141 |     let length = pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&tlv_data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                  --------------------------------------------------------------^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<&[u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |                  |
    |                  this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<&[u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:216:9
    |
214 |     ) -> Result<&V, ProgramError> {
    |          ------------------------ expected `Result<&V, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` because of return type
215 |         let data = get_bytes::<V>(self.get_data(), repetition_number)?;
216 |         pod_from_bytes::<V>(data)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `ProgramError`, found a different `ProgramError`
    |
    = note: `ProgramError` and `ProgramError` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-1.18.17/src/program_error.rs:14:1
    |
14  | pub enum ProgramError {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-2.0.1/src/program_error.rs:15:1
    |
15  | pub enum ProgramError {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:333:9
    |
331 |     ) -> Result<&mut V, ProgramError> {
    |          ---------------------------- expected `Result<&mut V, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` because of return type
332 |         let data = self.get_bytes_with_repetition_mut::<V>(repetition_number)?;
333 |         pod_from_bytes_mut::<V>(data)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `ProgramError`, found a different `ProgramError`
    |
    = note: `ProgramError` and `ProgramError` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-1.18.17/src/program_error.rs:14:1
    |
14  | pub enum ProgramError {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: `ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-2.0.1/src/program_error.rs:15:1
    |
15  | pub enum ProgramError {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:362:85
    |
362 |         let length = pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                     ^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:387:60
    |
387 |         let extension_ref = pod_from_bytes_mut::<V>(buffer)?;
    |                                                            ^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(&mut V, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<(&mut V, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:432:95
    |
432 |         let discriminator = ArrayDiscriminator::try_from(&self.data[type_start..length_start])?;
    |                                                                                               ^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(&mut [u8], usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<(&mut [u8], usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:439:88
    |
439 |                 pod_from_bytes_mut::<Length>(&mut self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                        ^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(&mut [u8], usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<(&mut [u8], usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError: From<TlvError>` is not satisfied
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:451:45
    |
451 |             Err(TlvError::TypeAlreadyExists.into())
    |                                             ^^^^ the trait `From<TlvError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `TlvError: Into<_>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `TlvError` to implement `Into<solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:490:97
    |
490 |         let length_ref = pod_from_bytes_mut::<Length>(&mut self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                                 ^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> /Users/johnliu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/spl-type-length-value-0.3.1/src/state.rs:556:84
    |
547 | ) -> Result<(), ProgramError> {
    |      ------------------------ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
556 |         usize::try_from(*pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&data[length_start..value_start])?)?
    |                          ----------------------------------------------------------^ the trait `From<spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, which is required by `Result<(), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`
    |                          |
    |                          this can't be annotated with `?` because it has type `Result<_, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::stake::instruction::StakeError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
    = note: required for `Result<(), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_program_error::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308, E0659.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `spl-type-length-value` (lib) due to 16 previous errors


Solution seems to be to add spl-type-length-value = "=0.3.0".
[dependencies]
solana-sdk = "1.18.17"
solana-client = "1.18.17"
spl-type-length-value = "=0.3.0"

https://github.com/cavemanloverboy/sol/pull/11
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/6897

The 0.3.1 crate has been yanked, so this should just work now
